# How to apply where condition on generated column in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
select groupId
,case 
 when 
(select count(*) from  event_attendees_mapping where 
event_schedule_id=scheduleId and employee_code='TJU_741')>0 then 1
else 0 end as isMyEvent from EventList_View
```

Using this Query I am crating new column at run time and give data like this :

```
groupId  isMyEvent
    '1', '0'
    '2', '0'
    '3', '0'
    '4', '1'
    '1', '0'
    '2', '0'
    '3', '0'
```

Now I am applying this Query for get Only those record whose `isMyEvent` is 1 using this Query:

```
 select groupId
    ,case 
     when 
    (select count(*) from  event_attendees_mapping where 
    event_schedule_id=scheduleId and employee_code='TJU_741')>0 then 1
    else 0 end as isMyEvent from EventList_View where isMyEvent=1
```

When I execute this Query then I am getting Error:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'isMyEvent' in 'where clause'
```

Can you please tell me where I am doing wrong I want to get data  when I execute last query like this:

```
groupId  isMyEvent
4           1
```

Please suggest me.

Comment: `isMyEvent` is virtual field, You can't add condition using virtual field. You should use Join query to get actual result.

Comment: but i cant Join coz we have  to pass Employee ID for check this dynamically please tell me other way

Comment: Ok, Update your Question with Database table ( `EventList_View` and `event_attendees_mapping` ) fields. Also mention table relationship.